# How can I get a HTML attribute value from the click event handler in amCharts

Tags: amcharts

I have added events listeners to my charts to catch clicks and perform actions.

```js
chart.addListener('clickGraphItem', handleClick);
```

`handleClick` is a function in which the event instance is available, but I can't seem to be able to retrieve an attribute value I beforehand added to my HTML.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of the clicked item in click handler function, use the `item` property of the event object passed to it.

It's an instance of the [GraphDataItem](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/GraphDataItem) object, which has `values` property, which in turn is an object holding various related values for this data item, like `value` (which we're interested in), high, low, etc.

```
function handleClick(event) {
  alert(event.item.values.value);
}
```

---

If you want to retrieve the attribute of the chart HTML element container on chart click, you can use `event.chart` object. The chart object contains `div` property, which is a reference to the chart container. You can access any of it's properties that way:

```
function handleClick(event) {
  console.log(event.chart.div.id);
}
```

To retrieve a non-standard property of an HTML element, use its [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method. I.e.:

```
function handleClick(event) {
  console.log(event.chart.div.getAttribute("chart-id"));
}
```

Comment: I wrote my post a bit too tired, I mistakenly thought the string was a custom name and replaced it in my example. Yes it is meant to be `clickGraphItem`. I must say, everything works just fine, except for the object of my post: get an attribute value within my `handleClick` function.

Comment: Do you mean you need to know how to get the value of the clicked data point?

Comment: Not at all, I'm referring to a HTML attribute I would have beforehand used in my chart block.

Comment: Do you mean you have attached some attributes to the chart div container and want to retrieve them on chart click?

Comment: Looks like that's what I missed, thanks a lot. I'll check this when I get the time :).

Comment: What if I added a custom attribute, say, `chart-id="asdf"`? Do I have to parse `chart.div.outerHTML`?

Comment: For non-standard attributes you you would need to use `getAttribute()` method of the element: `event.chart.div.getAttribute("chart-id")`

Comment: Since my post was more about getting a non-standard attribute value from the HTML element, could you please rework your answer accordingly in order for me to mark it as accepted? In short: all that is relevant to my question is your last comment. Thanks again :)

Comment: OK, I removed the part which does not seem relevant anymore and added note about non-standard attributes.